# Mage2 - Custom Grid Action 404 error

Tags: magento2, custom, action

I have create a custom admin grid for my blog module but "Add New Post" get a 404 page

> etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <virtualType name="BlogGridDataProvider" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collection" xsi:type="object" shared="false">Altravista\Blog\Model\ResourceModel\Post\Collection</argument>
            <argument name="filterPool" xsi:type="object" shared="false">BlogGirdFilterPool</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>

    <virtualType name="BlogGirdFilterPool" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FilterPool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="appliers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="regular" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\RegularFilter</item>
                <item name="fulltext" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FulltextFilter</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>

    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="blog_post_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">Altravista\Blog\Model\ResourceModel\Post\Collection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>

    <virtualType name="Altravista\Blog\Model\ResourceModel\Post\Collection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">altravista_blog_post</argument>
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Altravista\Blog\Model\ResourceModel\Post</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>

</config>
```

> view/ui_component/blog_post_listing.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">

    <!-- main part of the grid -->
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <!-- define where to find the date source -->
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">blog_post_listing.blog_post_listing_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">blog_post_listing.blog_post_listing_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <!-- define where to find the columns -->
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">blog_post_columns</item>

        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="add" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add a new Post</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/newAction</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>

    <!-- define the date source (must be the same than in argument/item/provider and argument/js_config/deps -->
    <dataSource name="blog_post_listing_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <!-- unique name for the grid -->
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">BlogGridDataProvider</argument>
            <!-- name of the data source same as in argument/js_config/provider -->
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">blog_post_listing_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">post_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">post_id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">post_id</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>

    <!-- define the columns of my grid -->
    <columns name="blog_post_columns">

        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <!-- Bookmarks behaviour -->
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">blog_post_listing.blog_post_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current</item>
                </item>
                <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="controlVisibility" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">blog_post_listing.blog_post_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="root" xsi:type="string">columns.${ $.index }</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.${ $.storageConfig.root}</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>

        <selectionsColumn name="ids">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <!-- define which field will be used as ID -->
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">post_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </selectionsColumn>

        <!-- Column ID -->
        <column name="post_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                    <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ID</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <!-- Column Title -->
        <column name="title">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">blog</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">title</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Title</item>
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <!-- Column Content -->
        <column name="content">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">blog</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">content</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Content</item>
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <!-- action columns edit and delete -->
        <actionsColumn name="actions" class="Altravista\Blog\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\BlogActions">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">107</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">post_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </actionsColumn>
    </columns>

</listing>
```

> Ui/Component/Listing/Column/BlogActions.php

```
    <?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Altravista\Blog\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;

/**
 * Class DepartmentActions
 */
class BlogActions extends Column
{
    /**
     * @var UrlInterface
     */
    protected $urlBuilder;

    /**
     * @param ContextInterface $context
     * @param UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory
     * @param UrlInterface $urlBuilder
     * @param array $components
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Prepare Data Source
     *
     * @param array $dataSource
     * @return array
     */
    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as &$item) {
                $item[$this->getData('title')]['edit'] = [
                    'href' => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl(
                        'blog/post/edit',
                        ['id' => $item['post_id']]
                    ),
                    'label' => __('Edit'),
                    'hidden' => false,
                ];
                $item[$this->getData('title')]['delete'] = [
                    'href' => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl(
                        'blog/post/delete',
                        ['id' => $item['post_id']]
                    ),
                    'label' => __('Delete'),
                    'hidden' => false,
                ];
            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

what i am wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing `<item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/newAction</item>` with `<item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/new</item>` and make sure that the file `Altravista/Blog/Controller/Adminhtml/Block/NewAction.php` exists

Comment: thanks a lot but adding this file Altravista/Blog/Controller/Adminhtml/NewAction.php it works . if you edit your answer is solved ;)

Comment: You can still make the change for the url config section. Magento automatically adds `Action` when looking for a controller for certain key words. so having the url '..../new' will map to `NewAction` class.